# Button doesn't change background when pressed

Tags: java, android, android-button

Basically I want to make a button that when pressed increases it's height to achieve the effect of 'sliding' out from behind that I saw on many apps and thought was cool but I can't seem to get it working. I have tried multiple ways:

Button.onTouch method with button.setwidth(50),

Button.onClick method with the same function as above,

and now I'm trying to use a Selector in XML this is what it looks like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dugme1_pressed" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dugme1"></item>
</selector>
```

I used Photoshop and created a simple button background:
[Button_Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9n0B.jpg)

and I created a button background that matches the effect that I want to achieve:
[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY7ly.jpg)

But when i start the app and press the button maybe 1-2 pixels below it change to a shade darker and the button background does not change.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

I tried the following two methods to achieve the effect but none of them worked:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height+=500;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
            params.height+=500;
        }
    });
```

Comment: it'll be easier for you if you change height and background in your code on button click

Comment: I've tried that using:
Button.setheight and Button.setBackground(Drawable)

Comment: share your code